# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyProject'

Tags: python, django, github

I'm collaborating with a group for an assignment we decided to use Django for, however, it seems that if one individual used upercase characters instead of lowercase characters (MyProject vs myproject) for example and therefore I often times get an error indicating
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyProject'`

I've changed it before & resolved it and then pushed it up to GitHub.. but every so often we encounter the same issue.

How can I fix this permanently so that it's no longer an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by renaming MyProject to myproject within the settings.py file

Thanks!